# Roboflow. After export images (after Preprocessing and Augmentation), didn't get all images in zip

Tags: roboflow

After export images (after Preprocessing and Augmentation), didn't get all images. Roboflow generate 721 images and after export (in zip) only got 30 images.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please invite help@roboflow.com to your public project and share the name of your workspace as a response here, so we may investigate further.

Would also be helpful to know what export format was selected

Comment: yes, of course. Export format was COCO

Comment: Thanks!  can you please invite help@roboflow.com to your public project and share the name of your workspace as a response here